# assign column name to select statement result without #tempopary tables

Tags: t-sql, select, alias

Look at this code:

```
DECLARE @bufferOrder INT = 1, @capacityOrder INT = 2, @priceOrder INT = 3, @angleSpeedOrder INT = 4

    SELECT 'buffer', @bufferOrder
UNION  
    SELECT 'capacity', @capacityOrder
UNION  
    SELECT 'price', @priceOrder
UNION  
    SELECT 'angle_speed', @angleSpeedOrder
```

Can I assign two column names without using a temporary table?

```
     [INSERT INTO @#tempTabel (columnName1,columnName2) + above code]
```

In way like this (pseudo code):

```
     above code +
     AS columnName1,columnName2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the column names in your first select statement. EG:

```
declare @int int = 1, @int2 int = 2, @int3 int = 3, @int4 int = 4;

select 'thing 1' as thing, @int as integer
union
select 'thing 2', @int2
union
select 'thing 3', @int3
```

I can easily add more things and more things to this.  Column names are defined in first select statement and stay that way unless they are changed aliases.